# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, http-get, postman

I'm getting this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://apidev.facu.la/api/json/infotag/search/?criteria=&infotagType=book&companyid=2. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 when trying to do this httpget call:

```
  $http({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'http://apidev.facu.la/api/json/infotag/search/?criteria=&infotagType=book&companyid=2',
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                alert('ok');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert('error');
                console.log(response);
            });
```

Any idea what am I missing? Postman calls work just fine.

### Update

Endpoint code:

```
  [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "/json/infotag/search/?criteria={criteria}&infotagType={infotagType}&companyid={companyid}")]
        public XElement InfoTagSearchXML_json(string criteria, string infotagType, int companyid)
        {
            return InfoTagSearchXML(criteria, infotagType, companyid);
        }
```

Comment: Method not allowed (Status code 405) means you don't have any OPTIONS method defined on your endpoint. It's mandatory for CORS requests.

See [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Can you give any details about your endpoint? (Language, Frameworks, etc.)

Comment: @Kronwalled just added the call to the question body. Thx for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a WebInvoke for Method OPTIONS to your ServiceContract like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "*")]
    void getOptions();

    ... other invokes
}

public class Service : ITestService
{
    public void getOptions()
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    }

    ... other invokes
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kronwalled. Once I'll add that, how can I utilize it for my call? Or that's the only thing I need to do?

Comment: It should be automatically invoked when you fire the GET request

Comment: Getting this error after the changes https://i.gyazo.com/83267cb7a48c2a1167c015f83b160079.png

Comment: Could you update the post how the whole service looks right now?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

then go to Web.config and remove these lines (if you have them)

```
<remove name="X-Powered-By" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Content-Type, Origin" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

and add the following code in WebApiConfig.cs file from App_Start folder:

```
var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                          "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                          "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```